# Pull request not able to be completed on Azure Devop

Tags: git, azure-devops, devops, pull-request

A colleague of mine has done a pull request that I cannot complete.

I've not done any of the commits included in the PR(Nor have I pushed them):

[image]

I've approved the request(and I'm the only reviewer):

[image]

But it won't auto-complete. If I try to complete it manually, I see this:

[image]

Here is my branch policy for develop(the target branch of this PR):

[image]

Why this PR cannot be merged??? We managed to merge it by adding another developer as reviewer and having him approve the PR, but it should possible to commit without this.

Thanks

**EDIT here are additional images**

The overview:

[image]

and the commits, even if I'm not sure you expect from it with all the thing that I had to blur:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are the pull request creator, since you disable the feature `Allow requestors to approve their own changes`, you can vote approve the pull request but the vote will not count toward the Minimum number of reviewers.

Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#require-a-minimum-number-of-reviewers): If **Allow requestors to approve their own changes** is selected, the creator of the pull request may vote on its approval. If not, they can still vote Approve on their pull request, but their vote won't count toward the Minimum number of reviewers.

**Update1**

Please check the below below and could you please mind sharing the same screenshots here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not the creator. The creator of the PR is my colleague, the one that did the commits.

Comment: Hi @J4N, I have updated the answer, please check the update1 and then kindly share the same screenshots here. Thanks for your help

Comment: I've added the missing screenshots. We have added another colleague to complete this PR, but I've to make sure it doesn't happen in the future.